# How to hide Youtrack Time-Tracking for groups/roles?

Tags: youtrack

I am using Youtrack as issue management. I am using the time tracking feature but i want to hide the "estimates" and the "spent time" for specific groups or roles.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make 'Estimation' and 'Spent time' fields private (in Custom Fields settings) and then grant 'Read Issue Private Field' and 'Update Issue Private Field' only to those users&groups (via roles) which should be able to see and edit time tracking.